# Ember.js: Should on-the-fly generated components have initializer injections?

Tags: ember.js

To my understanding, a component js file can be removed safely if it is an empty `Ember.Component.extend();` and has a template, and vice-versa. The component still works. But I've found that if there initializers injecting things into components, and the templates are expecting them to be there, deleting the empty js file breaks the component. Is this expected or a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is invalid. Turns out a component turns into a view if you delete the js file. This explains why the component injecting in initializers wasn't working.

Asked why this happens here: [Ember.js: Should component templates turn into views when the js file is deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846577/ember-js-should-component-templates-turn-into-views-when-the-js-file-is-deleted)