# Ember.js: Should component templates turn into views when the js file is deleted?

Tags: ember.js

I have a component with an empty `Ember.Component.extend();` and a template. When I delete the js file, the component template still works and renders, but as a view instead of a component. Since the template is in "templates/components/" and Ember can find it and render it, shouldn't Ember be smart enough to render it as a component and not a view? Or is this expected behavior?

Comment: Why do you say it's a view instead of a component?  Components are just an extension of views.

Comment: I used Ember Inspector to see it change types when I deleted the file.

Comment: My guess is that ember inspector is just incorrect in denoting that it's a view/component. It might search for a class of that type to decide if it is a component vs the deprecated views.